# See incoming requests to local ASP.NET development server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, service, request

Is there a way to view incoming requests to a local ASP.NET development server?

I'm making wcf service calls from a android app to a local development server. Something goes wrong somewhere along the way, and I need to view what data the server recieves.

Edit: The android app is local too... in an emulator.

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: @Rob: Yes, I can't seem to pick up my localhost traffic.

Comment: Are you sure the request arrives on your webserver? If yes, it means the problem is occuring in the pipeline of WCF, so you will be able to diagnose by using the WCF logs. More information on activating the logs here: http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/08/easing-the-pain-of-wcf-debugging/

Comment: @sonyc: Yes, I'm sure. For example, I'm sending Person, Car & House, but only Person and House arrives in the method in the WCF service. Therefore I also get the answer from the service. I will try to get logging to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First activate logging in your WCF application by following the steps by adding the following config in your web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="wcfTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\WcfTrace.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Then just double-click on the WcfTrace.svclog file generated at the root of your C:\ drive, in order to open it in the [SvcTraceViewer utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

if like you say you receive some of the parameters, but not all, maybe the interface you are calling from your Android app is an older one than the one deployed on your server?

Comment: This will only activate tracing, not message logging.

Comment: Yep, Ladislav is right, in order to activate message logging you need additional configuration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have troubles using Fiddler you can also use build-in WCF message logging and SvcTraceViewer.exe to check the log.